# Fechar uma modal depois de concluir a ação no quasar framework

Tags: vue.js, quasar

Eu tenho essa modal como um component filho:

```
<template>
    <q-modal v-model="opened" :content-css="{width: '40%', minHeight: '300px', padding: '0 15px'}" no-esc-dismiss no-backdrop-dismiss>
        <q-modal-layout >
            <q-toolbar slot="header" style="box-shadow: none !important; background: none !important; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) !important">
                <q-toolbar-title class="text-left" text-color="dark" style="margin: 15px 0 5px -25px">
                    Inserir novo Plano
                </q-toolbar-title>
            </q-toolbar>

            <q-toolbar slot="footer" color="white">
                <q-toolbar-title>
                    <slot name="btnfooter"/>
                    <q-btn @click="alteraData" label="alterar" color="blue" />
                </q-toolbar-title>
            </q-toolbar>


            <div class="">

            </div>
        </q-modal-layout>
    </q-modal>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'AlteraVencimento',
        props: ['abrirModal', 'novaData'],
        data() {
            return {
                opened: false,
            }
        },
        watch: {
            abrirModal: function(newVal, oldVal){
                this.opened = newVal;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            alteraData() {
                this.opened = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Quando o que estiver dentro da função `alteraData` terminar, a modal precisa ser fechada, mas como no exemplo acima, no momento em que eu seto `this.opened = false` a modal não abre mais, preciso atualizar a página para ela voltar a funcionar, mas isso acontece apenas quando a função `alteraData` é executada.

No component pai eu chamo a modal assim:

```
<modal-vencimento :abrirModal="openedVencimento">
    <q-btn color="light" class="float-right ml-1" label="Fechar" slot="btnfooter" @click="openedVencimento = false"/>
</modal-vencimento>
```

Então, ao clicar no botão fechar, ela fecha, se clicar para abrir em um outro botão do component pai para abrir, ela vai abrir, entretanto, se clicar no botão Alterar que faz a ação da função `alteraData` aí ela não abre mais.

Comment: Como está seu console no browser? Provavelmente ele sempre mostra o erro caso tiver.

Answer (score 0):

```
props: {
  abrirModal: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
},
computed: {
  modalControl: {
    get () {
      return this.abrirModal
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$emit('update:abrirModal', value)
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  alteraData() {
    this.modalControl = false;
  }
}
```

Para controle de modal eu sempre uso computed e emito eventos para ter o controle sobre o componente, eu deixaria o modal dessa forma e toda vez que a propriedade computada for alterada eu atualizo a props abrirModal.